# Sqlalchemy relationship to built-in type

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationship

I have something similar to this:

```
class Item(Base, DBBase):
  __tablename__ = 'item'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
  name = Column(String), nullable = True)
  comments = relationship('ItemComment')

class ItemComment(Base, DBBase):
  __tablename__ = 'itemcomments'
  item_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('item.id'), nullable = False, primary_key=True)
  comment = Column(String), nullable = False, primary_key=True)
```

I am wondering if it's possible to have the relationship map directly to the string so I can avoid handling ItemComment objects directly in the code. For example adding a new comment like this: `item.comments.append("hello")` or directly iterate over the string comments using `for comment in item.comments:`. I assume it could work with a @property, but is there a way to setup the relationship to handle it transparently ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly what [`Association Proxy`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html) extension is doing. In your case it would mean having the model like below:

```
class Item(Base, DBBase):
    __tablename__ = 'item'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = Column(String, nullable = True)
    comments = relationship('ItemComment')
    comms = association_proxy('comments', 'comment',
            creator=lambda comment: ItemComment(comment=comment),
            )

class ItemComment(Base, DBBase):
    __tablename__ = 'itemcomments'
    item_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('item.id'), nullable = False, primary_key=True)
    comment = Column(String, nullable = False, primary_key=True)
    def __init__(self, comment):
        self.comment = comment
```

and you can use it exactly like you wish:

```
my_item.comms.append("super")
print "All Comments: ", my_item.comms
```

One additional comment: you either need to specify the `creator` parameter (like in the code above) or else it is expected that you have a one-parameter constructor on `ItemComment` (like above), but one of the two suffice. I usually prefer explicit creation via `creator` parameter.
Also, you might want to rename `comments` to `_comments` and `comms` to `comments`.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I just had to add `cascade="all, delete-orphan"` to the relationship to be able to delete comments.